# How to fix bad request error in the web API application

Tags: asp.net-web-api

Hello I am getting the Bad Request Error Message in my post method while another post method of my project have same type of code which is working well.below I am going to write both Action method

Method which is giving bad request error message

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/tblProducts/AddToCart", Name = "GetAddWishList")]
public IHttpActionResult AddToCartList(tblWishList wishList)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var AltAddress = db.AddToCart(wishList.PrdName, wishList.PrdPrice, wishList.DisPrice, wishList.PrdStar, wishList.PrdDetails, wishList.UserId, wishList.Extra3, wishList.Extra4, wishList.PrdOffPercentage, wishList.ProductId);

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetAddWishList", new { id = wishList.UserId }, wishList);
}
```

and Action method which is working well

```
[Route("api/tblProducts/DynamicImage", Name ="GetProductImage")]
public IHttpActionResult AddDynamic(tblImage Review)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    var AltAddress = db.InsertDynamicImage(Review.ImageId, Review.ImagePath, Review.ImageCategory);

    return CreatedAtRoute("GetProductImage", new { id = Review.ImageId }, Review);
}
```

Update:
my tblWishlist class code

```
namespace MyMakeAnOrder.com.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class tblWishList
    {


        public string PrdName { get; set; }
        public decimal? PrdPrice { get; set; }
        public decimal? DisPrice { get; set; }
        public string PrdStar { get; set; }
        public string PrdDetails { get; set; }
        public string UserId { get; set; }
        public string WishStatus { get; set; }
        public string CartStatus { get; set; }
        public string Extra3 { get; set; }
        public string Extra4 { get; set; }
        public byte? PrdOffPercentage { get; set; }
        public string ProductId { get; set; }

        public virtual tblUser tblUser { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and my input which I am giving by fiddler

```
{"PrdName":"Nikeshoe","PrdPrice":"3000","DisPrice":"2000","PrdStar","PrdDetails":"Product is very good","UserId":"User1002","Extra3":"nothing","Extra4":"nothing","PrdOffPercentage":"20","ProductId":"Prd101"}
```

Comment: did you debugged ? are you getting model validation

Comment: yes i debug it and problem is that in the model state if block it is giving false and in the tblWishList object it is giving null means what i passed is not reaching in the action method

Comment: So the problem is different make sure to pass right input or modify your question

Comment: Ok i am adding tblWishList class code and my input in the question

Comment: your input is not a valid json

Comment: yes you are right i also find in PrdStar there is no value but when i clear it then it is giving new error An exception of type 'System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

Comment: something to do with Entity Framework. You need to see the exception details.and see your code for saving to DB

Answer (score -1):

You are getting BadRequest because **ModelState is not valid**. Set breakpoint on the method beginning and check what ModelState contains. You will receive information about validation errors.

Comment: yes i debug it and problem is that in the model state if block it is giving false and in the tblWishList ' object it is giving null means what i passed data by fiddler is not reaching in the action method,Please help me

Comment: Could you show definition of `tblWishList` class and data passed by fiddler?

Comment: Ok i am adding tblWishList class code and my input in the question

Comment: and this error message is also given by fiddler {"Message":"The request is invalid.","ModelState":{"wishList":["Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: g. Path '', line 0, position 0."]}}